# How do you delete multiple rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you delete multiple rows in excel, if I mark everything and try to delete it just deletes a single row.

Answer (score 4):

Content-wise: Mark the rows you'd like to delete and hit <kbd>Del</kbd>.

If you want to delete the rows, i.e. you want to reduce the number of rows:

- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, hit <kbd>-</kbd> (minus sign), then let go of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- hit <kbd>r</kbd> (for selecting **r** ows, you'll observe you can use <kbd>c</kbd> for **c** olumns)
- hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You're using backspace instead of the 'Delete' key. Use the 'Delete' key for that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm personally a fan of right-click (or control click on an Apple) and select delete from the pop-out menu.  That will also delete the rows, not just clear out the data.

Comment: "That will also delete the rows, not just clear out the data." -> This is especially important since Excel seems to mark cleared cells as if they are still in use. If you then use that Excel file as a data destination (for example, outputting data from Integration Services into the Excel file), you might find that your data begins to appear right below the last cleared row instead of at the beginning of the cleared cells. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: +1 - Selecting rows then hitting <delete> or <backspace> is deleting the contents of the last highlighted cell of the selection.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> will select all the rows down the current selection till a row which has text.

Click on the Row Header to highlight the entire row and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Click + Shift or Shift + Click on the Row Header (the number cell at the far left) to select multiple rows and either "delete" or right click to the context menu and delete.

Cheers,

CEC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete row contents, then select multiple rows from Row Headers (Left most of your screen normally) and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. However, if you want to delete rows entirely, then select multiple rows and then right click->Delete will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else also googling this solution:

Remember to remove any filters before attempting to delete multiple rows, otherwise it will only let you delete a single row even when selecting more than one.

Comment: This is more commentary then an actual answer to the author's question.  Please do not submit commentary as an answer in the future.